# What is a BORE Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>*In the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463), a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

If a word conforms to a special rule, we call it a BORE Word™. 
Use the examples below to find the rule.

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline
\bbox[yellow]{\textbf{BORE Words™}} & \bbox[yellow]{\textbf{Not BORE Words™}}\\\hline
\text{ANT} & \text{SPIDER}\\\hline
\text{ENVY} & \text{JEALOUSY}\\\hline
\text{FLAP} & \text{FLUTTER}\\\hline
\text{FUR} & \text{HAIR}\\\hline
\text{GREEN} & \text{BLUE}\\\hline
\text{IRK} & \text{RILE}\\\hline
\text{ONE} & \text{TWO}\\\hline
\text{ONYX} & \text{GEM}\\\hline
\text{REEF} & \text{CORAL}\\\hline
\text{ROOF} & \text{FLOOR}\\\hline
\text{TANG} & \text{ZEST}\\\hline
\end{array}$$

What is a BORE Word™?

Comment: This is a very BORING puzzle ;-)

Comment: Good catch @Tom

Comment: Can we have a csv version of this please?